# How to open Location Privacy Setting Page directly for ios11 ?As below code is not working , it opens setting screen only

Tags: ios

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code. It will take to App Specific Settings.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Comment: Please also comment it with reason when anyone downvote.